# Logic Error with PCSPIM MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, pcspim

I am working on a basic assembly language project, but I managed to mess up somewhere and the output always comes out as a FINE_FOUR (35 MPH+). If someone could help me debug this, I would really appreciate it.

```
.data
    STR_FIRSTPROMPT:    .asciiz "Enter your current driving speed in MPH (1 to 200): "                                      # Prompt for driving speed

    STR_SECONDPROMPT:   .asciiz "Enter the absolute speed limit specified for the road you are currently running on (15 - 70): "                # Prompt for speed limit

    STR_FIRSTERROR:     .asciiz "You made an invalid input for your current driving speed. Enter a valid input for your current driving speed. \n"      # Driving speed invalid input message

    STR_SECONDERROR:    .asciiz "You made an invalid input for the absolute speed limit. Enter a valid input for the absolute speed limit. \n"          # Speed limit invalid input message

    SAFE_DRIVER:        .asciiz "\nYou are a safe driver!\n"

    FINE_ONE:       .asciiz "You may recieve a $120 fine\n"                                                             # Fine for 1-20 MPH over speed limit

    FINE_TWO:       .asciiz "You may recieve a $140 fine\n"                                                         # Fine for 21-25 MPH over speed limit

    FINE_THREE:     .asciiz "You may recieve a class B misdemeanor and carries up to six months im jail and a maximum $1,500 in fines\n"                    # Fine for 26-34 MPH over speed limit

    FINE_FOUR:      .asciiz "You may recieve a class A misdemeanor and carries up to one year in jail and a maximum $2,500 in fines\n"                      # Fine for 35+ MPH over speed limit

.text
    .globl main

main:
    li $v0 4                        # System Call to print a message
    la $a0, STR_FIRSTPROMPT         # Loads address of STR_FIRSTPROMPT into $a0 register
    syscall                         # syscall to output message

    li $v0, 5                       # System Call to take user input
    syscall                         # Input value goes into $v1 register

    li $t0, 200                     # Loads 201 into $s0 register
    bgt $v0, $t0, first_error       # Checks if inputted value($v0) is greater than 201($s0)
    blt $v0, $zero, first_error     # Checks if inputted value($v0) is less than zero($zero)
    beq $v0, $zero, first_error     # Checks if inputted value($v0) is equal to zero($zero)
    j continue_execution1           # If input passes checks, continue_execution1

first_error:
    li $v0 4
    la $a0, STR_FIRSTERROR
    syscall

    li $v0 4
    la $a0, STR_FIRSTPROMPT
    syscall

    li $v0, 5                       # System Call to take user input
    syscall                         # Input value goes into $v1 register

    bgt $v0, $t0, first_error       # Checks if inputted value($v0) is greater than 201($s0)
    blt $v0, $zero, first_error     # Checks if inputted value($v0) is less than zero($zero)
    beq $v0, $zero, first_error     # Checks if inputted value($v0) is equal to zero($zero)
    move $t0, $v0                   # Move inputted speed to $t0 register **
    j continue_execution1           # If input passes checks, continue_execution1

continue_execution1:

    li $v0, 4                       # System call to print message
    la $a0, STR_SECONDPROMPT        
    syscall

    li $v0, 5                       # System Call to take user input
    syscall

    li $t7, 70
    li $t8, 15
    bgt $v0, $t7, second_error
    blt $v0, $t8, second_error
    move $t1, $v0                   # Move inputted speed limit to $t1 register **
    j continue_execution2           # Continue

second_error:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, STR_SECONDERROR
    syscall

    j continue_execution1           # Go back to continue_execution1

continue_execution2:
    sub $t2, $t0, $t1               # $t2 = $t0 - $t1

    li $t3, 1                       # Stores integer 1
    li $t4, 21
    li $t5, 26
    li $t6, 35

    blt $t2, $t3, safe_driver       # Driving under/the speed limit
    blt $t2, $t4, fine_one          # Driving 1-20 MPH over the speed limit
    blt $t2, $t5, fine_two          # Driving 21-25 MPH over the speed limit
    blt $t2, $t6, fine_three        # Driving 26-34 MPH over the speed limit
    bge $t2, $t6, fine_four         # Driving 35+ MPH over the speed limit

                                    # Printing Penalties now
safe_driver:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, SAFE_DRIVER
    syscall

    j END_PROGRAM

fine_one:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, FINE_ONE
    syscall

    j END_PROGRAM

fine_two:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, FINE_TWO
    syscall

    j END_PROGRAM

fine_three:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, FINE_THREE
    syscall

    j END_PROGRAM

fine_four:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, FINE_FOUR
    syscall

    j END_PROGRAM

END_PROGRAM:
    jr $31
```

Comment: Use your debugger/simulator to single step the code and see where it makes a wrong turn. Also, [edit] your question and use the code formatting button.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a debugging service.  You can search here or ask about how to debug, but assembly is no different from other languages: single step each line and see if the program state in between instructions make sense.  If you find something line that doesn't work the way you think it should, you can ask about that construct.  But debugging an whole program is out of scope here.

Comment: This kind of logic error is easier to debug in C.  Working C code translates easily to assembly (each statement, if, if-else, while, for, etc.. has an exact translation in assembly's if-goto-label style), so one approach is to get your logic working in C then take literally to assembly without making improvements during translation.  When we do that then the logic works the same in assembly as in C, and, you won't have to debug logic errors in assembly, only typos in translation..